# Why did Kaluza-Klein need an additional dimension?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein, unified-theories

Why did Kaluza-Klein need an additional dimension and not just treat the fourth dimension as a description of both time and space?
Assume that you can exchange the time dimension to a space dimension and vice versa with $cdt=dx_4$. In other words you treat the fourth dimension as a representative for both space and time. Then wouldn't you be able reduce the Kaluza-Klein theory to four dimensions and get rid of the scalar field, while keeping both gravity and electromagnetism?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): What is the sentence _"treat the fourth dimension as a representative for both space and time"_  supposed to mean?

Comment: Please do not edit an old question to ask a completely different question. Just ask a new question instead!

Answer (score 1):

Having one temporal dimension and three spatial dimensions means that the metric tensor has [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature) $(1,3)$ or $(3,1)$ depending on your convention.  Two temporal dimensions and two spatial dimensions would mean that the metric has signature $(2,2)$. Signature is a concrete property of a metric, so there is no sense in which a dimension could be both temporal and spatial.

The addition of the extra dimension in Kaluza-Klein is a feature, not a bug.  It (along with the assumption of compactness and the condition that the other metric components are independent of the additional coordinate) provides four extra degrees of freedom which can roughly be interpreted as the four components to the electromagnetic 4-potential.  Without the additional dimension, you have no additional freedom, and so no built-in 4-potential.

It's also worth noting that even with the 5th dimension Kaluza-Klein fails almost immediately e.g. in predicting the electron's charge, but that's not important for this discussion.